# Python's AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `Python3.4`. I am trying to open an application which supposedly uses `Python` and can't seem to get it working. I do receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pychess", line 24, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'
```

Comment: How are you executing this said application?

Comment: looks like [PyChess](http://www.pychess.org/) requires [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) or PyGObject to bind to GTK+3 the popular Gnome graphical backend. What platform are you on? Linux? Macintosh? Windows? You should read the [PyChess downloads](http://www.pychess.org/download/). Probably best way would be to install through your systems package manager on Linux.

Comment: I am executing it via ./pychess in it's respective directory, and I am using Linux.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error running [Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io) on CentOS 7.3.

Comment: I had the same error in Ubuntu, I simply did this : `sudo pip install PyGTK` . Everything started working.

Comment: What install method on what platform did you try? https://github.com/pychess/pychess/wiki/HowToInstall

Answer (score 1):

Install the dependency with `pip install PyGTK`, as João Cartucho suggests.